# TypeError with open function with configparser

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I have this problem with open() function in python. It returns me this:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Gianmarco\Documents\Progetto SARHIS\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    Write_N_Load()
  File "c:\Users\Gianmarco\Documents\Progetto SARHIS\main.py", line 27, in Write_N_Load
    with open("config.ini", "w") as f:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

The code is this one:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

def Write_N_Load():
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read("config.ini")
    firstStart = parser.get("sarhis","firstStart")
    if firstStart == "1":
        print("First Time Eh? Enter name: ")
        name = input()
        print("Oki Dokie")
        parser['sarhis'] = {"name": "{name}"}
        with open("config.ini", "w") as f:
            parser.write(f)
```

What i'm trying to do is to save `name` variable into `config.ini` file.

config.ini:

```
[sarhis]
firstStart = 1
```

Comment: Have you by chance declared a function called `open` yourself?

Comment: No, just the `with open(with open("config.ini", "w") as f:`

Comment: Do you mean `{'name': f'{name}'}` by the way? (Instead of raw `'{name}'`)

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work. The `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)` keep showing

Comment: How can i store it then? Just asking, learning python

Comment: Actually what you have should be fine (with regards to assigning a dictionary). Try opening the file outside this function, what happens?

Comment: It returns `NameError: name 'file' is not defined`. Added `global file` and `global parser`

Comment: You should provide the complete code with instructions on how to run it in the question. This needs more details

Comment: Here, updated the description

Comment: Running the code worked fine. Unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: How is it possible? What version of python you're using?

Comment: You should post the solution as an Answer, not by editing the question.

Comment: The reason why `from os import *` caused this is because it redefined `open` to be `os.open`. Which is what @rdas suggested.